# Admin panel builder

Tags: content-management-system, panel, admin

For years I've built by myself admin panel for my websites. Pros: full control on my products; cons: time demanding. So I tried to use wordpress but I really hate it; each spared minute is annulled if I try to personalize (for real) something.

Now, I'm looking a solution to easily and quickly build a control panel.
I'd like to add pieces instead of customize an huge prefixed panel.
I'd like to have an empty environment to add functional module (example: gallery management, customizable texts, etc.).

Basically I'm looking for an AdminPanel Builder much less invasive than most famous CMS.
I've tried to look for something but the web overflows with post about wordpress.

May you give me some good advices?

Answer (score 0):

You can save time by using frameworks.

Zend as a php backend and bootstrap 3 for html / css for example. Why not build your own panel based on that which accepts modules ? when finished you will only be writing new modules for new functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take the SaaS back-office + content query API road, to get all the content aspect of your app sorted?

I've been working for a solution like this for the past few months, it's definitely worth looking into to still being able to personalize stuff.